# CSS Background image only working inline html

Tags: html, css, background

This is my first question (and first post) on Stackoverflow. Hope to contribute more once I become skilled enough.

Anyway, I'm having trouble understanding why my background image appears when I reference it using css that's inline with my html, but not when I put it in a separate css stylesheet that the html links to.

**Here's what my inline css looks like, which works fine:**

```
<style>
    body {
        background: url('background.jpg') center center fixed;
        background-size: cover;
    }
</style>
```

My styles.css file is shown below, which contains the exact same code:

```css
<style>

 body {

  background: url('background.jpg') center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
 }

 p {

  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue' Helvetica;
  font-color: white;

 }

 h1 {

  color: white;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
  font-size: 3.5em;
  text-align: center
 }

 .textbox {

  background-color: beige;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue' Helvetica;
  font-weight: 200;

 }


</style>
```

...but it no longer shows the background image.  Everything else from the css file (paragraph formatting, text size/color, etc.) shows up in the browser just fine.

**Also, the html file, css file, and background image are all in the same directory.**  So I figured I don't need to use "/background.jpg", "../background.jpg", etc. which I've seen suggested in other cases in other posts on Stackoverflow.

I tried to find an answer to this but couldn't find one.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly does styles.css contain?

Comment: Hi, nice to see more people in the community, try to read and work with this site http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But, in a separate .css file, I typed the exact same code as above, linking to it in the html file by using:

Did you remove the `<style>` & `</style>` tags from the CSS file ? For example, like:

```
body {
    background: url('background.jpg') center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

These HTML tags are only required around your CSS rules if you're including CSS directly into your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

i need to see your file and folder structure.. makes sure the the stylesheet you are referring is in the same folder where the html is, if so the same code will do.. if you css is in another folder like in css/styles.css than you have to change the link as well as the href of stylesheet to something like ../image.png

the folder structure matters here

Answer (score 0):

Take the style tags out of your .css file.